# Silly square root puzzle

Tags: c#, square-root

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time, it seems to work fine when I enter input in the console, but when submitted my solution always fails test #3 (you can not see what the input or output is). The problem is here [Timus](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001). Here is the problem:

The problem is so easy, that the authors were lazy to write a statement for it!

**Input**

The input stream contains a set of integer numbers Ai (0 ≤ Ai ≤ 1018). The numbers are separated by any number of spaces and line breaks. A size of the input stream does not exceed 256 KB.

**Output**

For each number Ai from the last one till the first one you should output its square root. Each square root should be printed in a separate line with at least four digits after decimal point.

**Input:**

```
1427  0   

     876652098643267843 

5276538
```

**Output:**

```
2297.0716

936297014.1164

0.0000

37.7757
```

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ReverseRoot
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ulong> longs = new List<ulong>();

        string current = "";
        bool inNumber = false;

        string input = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
        {
            char c = input[i];
            if (inNumber && !char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                longs.Add(ulong.Parse(current));
                inNumber = false;
                current = "";
            }
            if (char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                inNumber = true;
                current += c;
            }
        }

        longs.Reverse(0, longs.Count);

        foreach (ulong n in longs)
        {
            double p = (Math.Truncate(Math.Sqrt(n) * 10000.0)) / 10000.0;
            Console.WriteLine("{0:F4}", p);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

I've also tried Rounding to four decimal places since the wording of the problem is not entirely clear:

```
        foreach (ulong n in longs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0:F4}", Math.Sqrt(n));
        }
```

I've tried numbers through the range of values in the console, not sure what it could be.

Comment: You should briefly describe the problem your code is trying to solve so that people don't need to visit that site in order to understand your question. An example of a simple input and the expected output would also help.

Comment: I think your code is failing when there are no spaces or line breaks after the last long value. Your code won't parse that last value because your logic requires `!char.IsDigit(c)` to trigger getting a value.

Comment: good catch hatchet, that's true!

Answer (score 8):

this gives the output thats on the site....  (your truncate one doesn't, so rounding is needed)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{            
   Console.In.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(ulong.Parse)
        .Reverse()
        .Select(n => Math.Sqrt(n).ToString("F4"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

Comment: Ah, the joys of fluent programming :)